# Are Mercurial hgrc section headings lowercase?

Tags: python-2.7, mercurial, hgrc

When using uppercase section headings in any hgrc or mercurial.ini file, things behave strange or stop working. Using e.g. an uppercase `[PATHS]` section like:

```
[PATHS]
default = http://myrepo
```

results in the following error:

> abort: repository default not found!

It seems that these section headings need to be lower case, although I cannot find any references about this in the [official hgrc section page](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html). I thought the Python `ConfigParser.ConfigParser()` is used for this and that its default behaviour is to convert those names to lowercase. Tested this with 4.0.1 and 4.1.1

But apparently not?

Comment: One might argue that this is either a documentation bug or a legit bug in the configuration parser. You may want to consider reporting a bug on the mercurial bugzilla: https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/.

Comment: I think that both hgrc section and config keys are case-sensitive and must then be in lowercase but nothing either in the code or in the documentation is indicating this limitation.

Comment: It doesn't say that the section headings (or anything) is case-agnostic - so why should they?